# Converting csv data ([]string) to float64 with strconv then summing the data

Tags: csv, go

I am trying to sum data from a CSV file I created from a previous function. Here is a snippet of the file:

```
datetime,open,high,low,close,volume
2020-11-09 00:00,69.58,137.45,69.00,100.00,273517274.00
2020-11-10 00:00,104.65,128.80,101.75,107.00,141284399.00
2020-11-11 00:00,109.00,114.45,96.76,98.42,96648953.00
2020-11-12 00:00,95.98,106.60,89.15,90.00,149794913.00
```

[For context: this is historical price data for Rolls-Royce Holdings stock price from Yahoo finance. I plan to use up to 200 rows].

The problem I am facing is converting the `[]string` data from the CSV to float64. The `ParseFloat()` function is trying to convert my headings and obviously can't as it is 'invalid syntax'. Here is the error code:

```
Error converting string: strconv.ParseFloat: parsing "open": invalid syntaxError converting string: strconv.ParseFloat: parsing "high": invalid syntaxError converting string: strconv.ParseFloat: parsing "low": invalid syntaxError converting string: strconv.ParseFloat: parsing "close": invalid syntaxError converting string: strconv.ParseFloat: parsing "volume": invalid syntax&{ 0 0 0 0 0}
```

My code is below for reference:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

const file = "./rr.csv"

// Data struct is the data from the csv file
type Data struct {
    datetime string
    open     float64
    high     float64
    low      float64
    close    float64
    volume   float64
}

func readAmounts(r []string) (d *Data, err error) {
    d = new(Data)
    open := r[1]
    d.open, err = strconv.ParseFloat(open, 64)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error converting string: %v", err)
    }
    high := r[2]
    d.high, err = strconv.ParseFloat(high, 64)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error converting string: %v", err)
    }
    low := r[3]
    d.low, err = strconv.ParseFloat(low, 64)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error converting string: %v", err)
    }
    close := r[4]
    d.close, err = strconv.ParseFloat(close, 64)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error converting string: %v", err)
    }
    volume := r[5]
    d.volume, err = strconv.ParseFloat(volume, 64)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error converting string: %v", err)
    }
    return d, nil
}

func main() {
    csvFile, err := os.Open(file)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    r := csv.NewReader(csvFile)
    lines, err := r.Read()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    data, err := readAmounts(lines)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Error reading file: %v", err)
    }
    fmt.Println(data)

}
```

I am just printing the data to see if the ParseFloat() works and then I'll create a function to sum the columns.
So, what I'm asking is; how do I ignore the header line and just read through the numerical lines.

FYI: I've read other answers (eg: FieldsPerRecord) but they haven't worked for my specific problem, as I am then trying to sum the whole columns afterwards.

Comment: You seem to be operating under the assumption that `Read()` returns lines. It doesn't It returns only the next line.

Comment: If you want to read all the lines, use `ReadAll()`. Otherwise, call `Read()` in a loop for each line.

Comment: In either case, to skip the header, do that by, well... skipping the header. Just don't pass the first line to `readAmounts`

Comment: Thank you @Flimzy. Just a Q, how would you go about skipping the header in readAmounts()? I feel like I'm missing something very obvious here haha

Comment: @swan The way to skip depends on whether you update the application to call Read in a loop or ReadAll.  If you slurp up all the records with ReadAll, then process records[1:].  If you call Read in a loop, then call Read once before the loop to ignore the header.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the file into a CSV, then process row by row the file:

```golang
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/csv"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "strconv"
)

const file = "./data.csv"

// Data struct is the data from the csv file
type Data struct {
    datetime string
    open     float64
    high     float64
    low      float64
    close    float64
    volume   float64
}

func main() {

    f, err := ioutil.ReadFile(file)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    rawData, err := readCsv(f, ',')
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    amounts, err := readAmounts(rawData[1:])
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", amounts)

}

func readAmounts(r [][]string) ([]Data, error) {
    var d []Data = make([]Data, len(r))
    var err error
    for i, row := range r {

        d[i].datetime = row[0]
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Error converting string: %v", err)
        }
        d[i].open, err = strconv.ParseFloat(row[1], 64)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Error converting string: %v", err)
        }
        d[i].high, err = strconv.ParseFloat(row[2], 64)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Error converting string: %v", err)
        }
        d[i].low, err = strconv.ParseFloat(row[3], 64)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Error converting string: %v", err)
        }
        d[i].close, err = strconv.ParseFloat(row[4], 64)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Error converting string: %v", err)
        }

        d[i].volume, err = strconv.ParseFloat(row[5], 64)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Printf("Error converting string: %v", err)
        }
    }
    return d, nil

}

func readCsv(data []byte, separator rune) ([][]string, error) {
    csvReader := csv.NewReader(bytes.NewReader(data))
    csvReader.Comma = separator
    lines, err := csvReader.ReadAll()
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return lines, nil
}
```

Example of output:

```
[{datetime:2020-11-09 00:00 open:69.58 high:137.45 low:69 close:100 volume:2.73517274e+08} {datetime:2020-11-10 00:00 open:104.65 high:128.8 low:101.75 close:107 volume:1.41284399e+08} {datetime:2020-11-11 00:00 open:109 high:114.45 low:96.76 close:98.42 volume:9.6648953e+07} {datetime:2020-11-12 00:00 open:95.
98 high:106.6 low:89.15 close:90 volume:1.49794913e+08}]
```

#### NOTE:

You can find some example of code that work using the `CSV` library, you can view the following repositories: https://github.com/alessiosavi/GoSFTPtoS3

Answer (score 0):

I've commented out the program so that's easy to understand. Basic idea is to ignore the header. Also, as you're indexing and getting the fields of the record; it's better to put a check for the number of fields that are present in the record (`FieldsPerRecord`).

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/csv"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "strconv"
)

// file stores the filepath
const file = "./rr.csv"

// Data store metadata
type Data struct {
    datetime string
    open     float64
    high     float64
    low      float64
    close    float64
    volume   float64
}

// s2f converts string to float64
func s2f(str string) (float64, error) {
    f, err := strconv.ParseFloat(str, 64)
    if err != nil {
        return 0, fmt.Errorf("Error converting string \"%v\" to float", err)
    }
    return f, nil
}

// ReadAmounts processes the fields from the record and stores them in Data
func ReadAmounts(r []string) (*Data, error) {

    var (
        dt     = r[0]
        open   = r[1]
        high   = r[2]
        low    = r[3]
        close  = r[4]
        volume = r[5]

        d   = new(Data)
        err error
    )

    d.datetime = dt

    d.open, err = s2f(open)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    d.high, err = s2f(high)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    d.low, err = s2f(low)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    d.close, err = s2f(close)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    d.volume, err = s2f(volume)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    return d, nil
}

func main() {
    // Open the file
    file, err := os.Open(file)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }

    // CSV Reader
    r := csv.NewReader(file)
    // Set Options for the reader
    {
        r.Comma = ','             // Delimiter
        r.TrimLeadingSpace = true // Trim the leading spaces
        r.FieldsPerRecord = 0     // Rows should have same number of columns as header
        r.ReuseRecord = true      // Reuse the same backing array (Efficient)
    }

    // Alternatively, r.ReadAll() could be also used and slicing it using [1:] ignores
    // the header as well.

    // Ignore header
    _, _ = r.Read()

    for {
        // Read record (one by one)
        record, err := r.Read()
        if err != nil {
            // Exit out. Done!
            if errors.Is(err, io.EOF) {
                break
            }
            // Log and continue
            log.Printf("Error reading record: %v\n", err)
            continue
        }

        // Process
        data, err := ReadAmounts(record)
        if err != nil {
            // Log and continue
            fmt.Printf("Error reading record: %v\n", err)
            continue
        }

        // Print the filled Data struct
        fmt.Printf("Record: %+v\n", *data)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Record: {datetime:2020-11-09 00:00 open:69.58 high:137.45 low:69 close:100 volume:2.73517274e+08}
Record: {datetime:2020-11-10 00:00 open:104.65 high:128.8 low:101.75 close:107 volume:1.41284399e+08}
Record: {datetime:2020-11-11 00:00 open:109 high:114.45 low:96.76 close:98.42 volume:9.6648953e+07}
Record: {datetime:2020-11-12 00:00 open:95.98 high:106.6 low:89.15 close:90 volume:1.49794913e+08}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some different options:

1. Skip parsing the first line. This assumes every file starts with a header.
2. Skip lines that have parsing errors. The easiest method, but hard to debug when things go wrong.
3. If the first line has parsing errors, skip it, because it is probably a header row.

On a side note, you should handle errors properly in your code, which you are not currently doing.